# How do I use "GROUP BY"?

Tags: database, 8

How do I use `GROUP BY` to display the result by group (email)?
this is my file .php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 */
namespace Drupal\gestion_contact\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
class GestionContactController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function admin() {


        $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {contact}");

            $node = $result->fetchAll();

        return array(
            '#theme' => 'gestion_contact',
            '#nodes'=> $node,

        );
    }
    public function delete($id)
    {

        db_delete('contact')
            ->condition('id_contact', $id)
            ->execute();
        drupal_set_message(t('Your form has been deleted'));

        $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {contact}");

        $node = $result->fetchAll();
        return array(
            '#theme' => 'gestion_contact',
            '#nodes' => $node,

        );
    }
    public function afficher()
    {

        $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {contact} WHERE vu = :vu",
            array(':vu' => 'false'));
        $node = $result->fetchAll();
        return array(
            '#theme' => 'nouveaux_contact',
            '#nodes' => $node,
        );
    }
}
```

[image: this is a log messages]
[image: this is my table contact]

Comment: Look at second line `...BY: SELECT * FROM...`, this is causing error. Look at Edit 1 on my answer, by default Drupal use sql_mode with 'only_full_group_by', this means that you cannot use a aggregate function (GROUP BY) with non aggregated column. In this Edit also provide an example to solve this.

Comment: I did not understand, what  is the problem exactly? how to solve it? can you write me an example?

Comment: Use `SELECT email` instead of `SELECT *`, if you only need email column.

Comment: I need all the column, how to do aggregation with GROUP BY?

Comment: @Vagner  I am waiting for your answer

Comment: sry, but how I can guess which field you want and which columns has in contact table that you created? I already provide how to create a select and why your select not working. To see more SQL reference about GROUP BY see MySQL docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: thanx for your help

Answer (score 3):

Follow an example:

```
$result = db_query('SELECT tid, count(tid) AS count FROM {taxonomy_term_field_data} WHERE vid <> :vid GROUP BY tid', array(':vid' => 'tags'));
```

But, from docs...

> **Deprecated**
>
> as of Drupal 8.0.x, will be removed in Drupal 9.0.0. Instead, get a
>   database connection injected into your service from the container and
>   call query() on it. For example, $injected_database->query($query,
>   $args, $options);

More info in [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_query/8.0.x).

**Edit 1:**

Drupal set by default sql_mode with 'only_full_group_by', in your case when you use `SELECT *`, an database exception is throw, look in your log, you will see something like this:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'database.table.field' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause.

So to correct this you must aggregate all fields in your SELECT list. If you only need e-mail list something like this can solve:

```
db_query('SELECT email FROM {contact} GROUP BY email');
```

Comment: I created this code but i doesn't work "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."                                       $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {contact} GROUP BY Email ");

            $node = $result->fetchAll();

Comment: Check your db if you have this table `{contact}` with this field `email`. Run this select in your preferred app and see the results.

Comment: yes, I have this table and field , when I run the instruction without group by,it working properly

Comment: @Sony added more information.